# Java Security is blocking the application to launch

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, java-security

We are creating Java Web start Application with JNLP and when we try to launch the application we are getting this issue

[image: We are creating Java Web start Application with JNLP and when we try to launch the application we are getting this issue]

This is my JNLP file

```
<jnlp spec="1.0+" codebase="http://localhost:8080/" href="EDoc.jsp?url=<%=request.getParameter("url")%>&file=<%=request.getParameter("file")%>">
    <information>
        <title>Jnlp Testing</title>
        <vendor>YONG MOOK KIM</vendor>
        <homepage href="http://localhost:8080/">
            <description>Testing Testing</description>
        </homepage>
    </information>
    <security>
        <all-permissions/>
    </security>
    <resources>
        <j2se version="1.6+"/>
        <jar href="SignatureApplet-1.0.jar"/>
        <extension name="Java Help" href="help.jnlp"/>
    </resources>
    <application-desc main-class=" com.narola.digitalsignature.EDoc2Jnlp">
        <argument><%=request.getParameter("url")%></argument>
        <argument><%=request.getParameter("file")%></argument>
    </application-desc>
</jnlp>
```

Comment: Please read this : https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please share your code

Comment: Please check now I have added the JNLP file

Comment: According to the java docs if the application name is missing the app will be blocked. Add a `<application-desc name="the app"`. you can also add the site to teh exception list

Comment: @KennethClark I am still getting the same issue when I am adding the app name and I have already added the site name to exception list.

Comment: Take a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6610266/how-to-grant-all-permissions-to-java-applet-through-jnlp-without-popups.

Comment: @KennethClark this one is also not working. still getting the same issue.